# how do I work with python, and the interface builder in xcode 4.2?

Tags: python, xcode, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

The selected answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276967/python-in-xcode-4) tells me how to work with python in xcode 4. This article, shows that you can design an interface using the interface builder, and hook up buttons to python functions etc. and then run it through py2app. However, i can't find the options to do so. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post you refer to is trying to set up xcode 4 for python development, but not necessarily with pyobjc. If you want to set it up with pyobjc, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843508/pyobjc-on-xcode-4).

I myself had difficulty in making the templates work; it will need some renaming of classes and editing of placeholders. Projects from XCode 3 work, though, and you can use them as a starting point. Just make sure that when you are adding IBOutlets/IBActions, put them on the top level of your app delegate/controller, so that Interface builder can find them.