# Python auto completion in Xcode 4

Tags: python, xcode, scripting, code-completion

I'm using Xcode 4 to write python scripts ([stackoverflow.com/questions/5276967/python-in-xcode-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276967/python-in-xcode-4))

I'm wondering if there's a way to get auto completion in Xcode 4. Is there a way to set up a python path, so that I can't point xcode to my custom python modules and get those to be scanned for auto completion. I don't even get auto completion for the standard modules such as math och os.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this is that XCode just was never meant to be an IDE for python.
Therefore XCode won't have any python specific IDE features, except maybe highlighting, without external plugins and addons.

As seen [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonEditors)

Xcode -
MacOS X -
Free IDE and text editor. Includes Python syntax coloring.

those are the supported features officially, unless someone develops something that helps out you are probaly stuck on this one.

additionallly while reading through your link at the end of the accepted post

> Say, "Hello, code completion and syntax highlighting." Note that it's not as advanced
>   as it is with C, C++, or Objective-C but it is definitely better than using IDLE.

isnt that what you want?

hope this helps, tell me if you have any more questions