# How to choose python 3.5.1 executable for project on Xcode 7?

Tags: xcode, xcode7, python-3.5

I want to set up a python 3 project in Xcode, but I fail in the step where I'm asked to choose an executable for the scheme. See step 16 in the answer to [Python in Xcode 4+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276967/python-in-xcode-7).

I use "which python3" to locate the executable:

```
$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

but Xcode does not let me choose python3 from "/usr/local/bin" by clicking on it:

[image]

If I try following the suggestion of trojanfoe below to uncover the symbolic link through:
    ls -l /usr/local/bin/python3
I get to "../Cellar/python3/3.5.1/bin/python3" which in turn is a symbolic link pointing to "../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3" which finally points at "Python3.5" in that directory. However, my Xcode also is not willing to let me select this file:

[image]

I'm running Xcode 7.3.1 in OS X 10.11.4. I've installed python 3.5.1 with home-brew.

Comment: I also have the same problem. Anybody?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the file selection window right-click on python3.5 and select quick look. Close the quick look window and python3.5 will become selectable. 
(images attached show workflow referencing the newer python3.6 - it is the same for all python releases).

[Right click on python executable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiRz6.png)

[Pop up window will be shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u48q1.png)

[Select quicklook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9mYx.png)

[Python executable has been selectable and "choose" button is clickable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdlpv.png)

Comment: u are true champion.

Answer (score 2):

I just finished wrestling with this for about three hours.
    Okay, short answer (which marken, above, deserves credit for): Just right-click the dimmed out python3 executable, then click "Quick Look", then hit the space bar to exit the quick-look, and notice the executable is now selected, and just hit enter, or click "Choose".
    I have the following explanation to offer. The reason for our ability to see--*but not to select*--the python3 executable is that Homebrew uses a file alias, /usr/local/bin/python3, which brew's installation is given restricted permissions that Xcode is unable to pre-select, for reasons I am unsure of. (You might notice you can tediously select the executable at each and every runtime.) The alias points, in my case, to the Homebrew "Cellar"; for your reference, using the Terminal app to execute,`ls -al /usr/local/bin/python3` reveals that my it's aliased to the true Homebrew python3 executable located at `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/bin/(python3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just right click and Quick Look option works. File becomes selectable, and then you can choose to specify it as an executable in your Xcode project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Anaconda, you can install the `python.app` package:

```
conda install python.app
```

Then, in Xcode, select `</path/to/anaconda-environment>/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python`.

(Note: Do not select the `python.app` in the `bin` directory (`</path/to/anaconda-environment>/bin/python.app`), which will result in some error regarding the Mach-O header.)