# No executable files in python 3.7.7 for Xcode 11.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, xcode

I have installed Python 3.7.7 via Homebrew in the terminal. However, I could not find any executable file even though I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276967/python-in-xcode-4).

[image]

All files here are aliases, and cannot be executed. What should I do next to create a file in Xcode?

Comment: What do you need to do with the files? Why must they be executable? And to find the path of python3, run `type python3` in the terminal

Comment: Why do you want to use Xcode? As far as I know, it offers no IDE support for Python, and if you just need a text editor, there are plenty of more lightweight choices. Time to learn Emacs or vim!

Comment: @TurePålsson This is because I previously performed my C files in Xcode. Now I changed my mind to use visual studio rather than wasting hours to fix this issue.