# How to change a python version, when creating a project in Xcode

Tags: python, xcode, kivy

I created a simple Kivy app using Anaconda (Python 3.8.8). I followed the steps listed on: https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios to install Kivy and create an Xcode project. However, the project is created with an python version 3.8.2, which is located in `/usr/bin/`, but the Anaconda is located in `/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3`. I've tried `Conda activate base` before running `toolchain create <title> <app_directory>`, but Xcode still uses the 3.8.2 version. This results in errors, because all packages were installed for the 3.8.8 version. When running `python --version` in terminal , I get `Python 3.8.8`

The question: how to create an Xcode project with the Python 3.8.8 version?

Comment: Have you tried virtual enviornment ?

Comment: sorry, I don't  get it, what do you mean by that?

Comment: I followed this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276967/python-in-xcode-4 but now I get a new error: ```shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted```

Comment: Learn how to use python virtual enviornment. I think you don't know what a virtual enviornment is you can move here -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5vscPTWKOk  and learn something new.

Comment: I think it's fair to suggest using a virtual environment. However, that does not address the issue that xcode is breaking the non-virtual python3 environment on MacOS. There is no reason `python3` should reference one version while `pip3` references another. Yes there are workarounds, and possible better practices, but the issue remains that xcode breaks the global python3 environment and I don't think that issue should be brushed aside just because you can make a virtual environment.